# What is the slowest growing function that is total but not primitive recursive?

Tags: functions, computability, recursion

For what I have in mind is the Ackermann-Buck function. If there isn't a slowest growing function do you have examples of other function slower growing than Ackermann-Buck's function?

Comment: A function that returns a cryptographic hash of the Ackerman-Buck functions output would be total, not primitive recursive and would not grow.

Answer (score 4):

There can't be such a function.  A rough proof by contradiction follows.

Assume $ f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $ is the smallest growing total recursive function that is not primitively recursive.  Then you can construct $ g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $ such that.

$$  g(x) = \begin{cases} 
      f(x/2) & \text{x is even} \\
      f((x-1)/2) & \text{x is odd}
   \end{cases}
$$

$g$ will grow half as quickly as $f$ but will not be primitively recursive.  However since $f$ was assumed to be the smallest growing non primative function this is a contradiction.